# How can I import relationships csv file into Neo4j with labels including special characters?

Tags: import, neo4j, properties, special-characters

I have an edge_d.csv file like the following:

```
:START_ID,:END_ID,:TYPE,reaction
CPD-12497,CPD-12498,direct,"RXN-11539"
CO-A,CPD-14010,direct,"RXN-12965"
CPD-8186,CPD-14010,direct,"RXN-12965"
```

everything works fine if I do not include the last column, "reaction". However, when I add this column my graph database can not be built anymore. I use neo4j-import tool like this:

```
/neo4j-import --into graph.db --id-type string --quote "\"" --bad-tolerance 100000 --nodes nodes1.csv, node2.csv --relationships edge_t.csv,edge_s.csv,edge_p.csv,edge_d.csv
```

Comment: Are you getting some error message?

Comment: Hi Bruno, No I don't get an error message. I am running Neo4j on a cloud machine and it simply gets stuck: nodes--done indexing --done relationships -- done. and then it gets stuck

Comment: Tried removing the `--quote` option? (" is the default value)

Comment: I only removed --quote option from makefile as you suggested, but it still does not work. Should I remove " characters from reaction field in the data?

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work :-(. Gets stuck at the same step.

Comment: If you have a chance to touch up the data, that's often quicker than trying to convince the loader on something. I'd just remove the quotes with a quick sed operation: e.g. `sed -i 's/"//g'' *.csv", but be careful and test before running on the actual data set.

Comment: Thank you Gabor. I did remove the quotation (both from makefile and data) as suggested by Bruno first, but it got stuck at the same step in make data. I also do not know if my header should include reaction:string or just reaction.

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/options/) about the `--quote` options says:

> Character to treat as quotation character for values in CSV data.
>   Quotes can be escaped by doubling them, for example "" would be
>   interpreted as a literal ". You cannot escape using . Default: "

Try removing the `--quote` option. This way:

```
/neo4j-import --into graph.db --id-type string --bad-tolerance 100000 --nodes nodes1.csv, node2.csv --relationships edge_t.csv, edge_s.csv, edge_p.csv, edge_d.csv
```

Comment: update: In the header line of the data file, I changed reaction to myreaction and I kept the quotations on the strings in the corresponding column, now the error i get is: "Caused by:Extra column not present in header on line 0 in /edge_d.csv with value myreaction"

Comment: i forgot to say that I checked and the extra column myreaction "is" very well present in the edge_d.csv. I really have no clue why neo4j--import does not work?